# More concise way to build a configuration class using environment variables?

Tags: raku

I have a class `Configuration` that reads in environment variables:

```
class Configuration {
    has $.config_string_a;
    has $.config_string_b;
    has Bool $.config_flag_c;

    method new() {
        sub assertHasEnv(Str $envVar) {
            die "environment variable $envVar must exist" unless %*ENV{$envVar}:exists;
        }

        assertHasEnv('CONFIG_STRING_A');
        assertHasEnv('CONFIG_STRING_B');
        assertHasEnv('CONFIG_FLAG_C');

        return self.bless(
            config_string_a => %*ENV{'CONFIG_STRING_A'},
            config_string_b => %*ENV{'CONFIG_STRING_B'},
            config_flag_c => Bool(%*ENV{'CONFIG_FLAG_C'}),
        );
    }
}

my $config = Configuration.new;

say $config.config_string_a;
say $config.config_string_b;
say $config.config_flag_c;
```

Is there a more concise way to express this? For example, I am repeating the environment variable name in the check and the return value of the constructor.

I could easily see writing another, more generic class that encapsulates the necessary info for a config parameter:

```
class ConfigurationParameter {
    has $.name;
    has $.envVarName;
    has Bool $.required;

    method new (:$name, :$envVarName, :$required = True) {
        return self.bless(:$name, :$envVarName, :$required);
    }
}
```

Then rolling these into a List in the `Configuration` class. However, I don't know how to refactor the constructor in `Configuration` to accommodate this.

Comment: On my phone, but a simple change to your original code would be to have the assert return the value. 
Then you can call it in the self.bless part.

Comment: What scimon said.

Comment: I am think the most Perl6 ish way would be a `is env<:required>` trait. Now I have to work out how to write it. 
This way you could write `has $.config_name is env<:required>` and it would just work... Hmmmmm

Comment: https://github.com/Scimon/p6-Trait-Env : So I took Jonathan's code from below plus some tricks I got from Liz and made this. 
It should be up in CPAN soon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most immediate change that comes to mind is to change `new` to be:

```
method new() {
    sub env(Str $envVar) {
        %*ENV{$envVar} // die "environment variable $envVar must exist"
    }

    return self.bless(
        config_string_a => env('CONFIG_STRING_A'),
        config_string_b => env('CONFIG_STRING_B'),
        config_flag_c => Bool(env('CONFIG_FLAG_C')),
    );
}
```

While `//` is a definedness check rather than an existence one, the only way an environment variable will be undefined is if it isn't set. That gets down to one mention of `%*ENV` and also of each environment variable.

If there's only a few, then I'd likely stop there, but the next bit of repetition that strikes me is the names of the attributes are just lowercase of the names of the environment variables, so we could eliminate that duplication too, at the cost of a little more complexity:

```
method new() {
    multi env(Str $envVar) {
        $envVar.lc => %*ENV{$envVar} // die "environment variable $envVar must exist"
    }
    multi env(Str $envVar, $type) {
        .key => $type(.value) given env($envVar)
    }

    return self.bless(
        |env('CONFIG_STRING_A'),
        |env('CONFIG_STRING_B'),
        |env('CONFIG_FLAG_C', Bool),
    );
}
```

Now `env` returns a `Pair`, and `|` flattens it in to the argument list as if it's a named argument.

Finally, the "power tool" approach is to write a trait like this outside of the class:

```
multi trait_mod:<is>(Attribute $attr, :$from-env!) {
    my $env-name = $attr.name.substr(2).uc;
    $attr.set_build(-> | {
        with %*ENV{$env-name} -> $value {
            Any ~~ $attr.type ?? $value !! $attr.type()($value)
        }
        else {
            die "environment variable $env-name must exist"
        }
    });
}
```

And then write the class as:

```
class Configuration {
    has $.config_string_a is from-env;
    has $.config_string_b is from-env;
    has Bool $.config_flag_c is from-env;
}
```

Traits run at compile time, and can manipulate a declaration in various ways. This trait calculates the name of the environment variable based on the attribute name (attribute names are always like `$!config_string_a`, thus the `substr`). The `set_build` sets the code that will be run to initialize the attribute when the class is created. That gets passed various things that in our situation aren't important, so we ignore the arguments with `|`. The `with` is just like `if defined`, so this is the same approach as the `//` earlier. Finally, the `Any ~~ $attr.type` check asks if the parameter is constrained in some way, and if it is, performs a coercion (done by invoking the type with the value).

Answer (score 5):

So I mentioned this in a comment but I figured it would be good as an actual answer. I figured this would be useful functionality for anyone building a Docker based system so took Jonanthan's example code, added some functionality for exporting Traits Elizabeth showed me and made [Trait::Env](https://modules.perl6.org/dist/Trait::Env:cpan:SCIMON)

Usage is :

```
use Trait::Env;
class Configuration {
    has $.config_string_a is env;
    has $.config-string-b is env(:required);
    has Bool $.config-flag-c is env is default(True);
}
```

The `:required` flag turns on `die` if not found. And it plays nicely with the `is default` trait. Attribute names are upper cased and `-` is replaced with `_` before checking `%*ENV`.

I have a couple of planned changes, make it throw a named Exception rather than just die and handle Boolean's a bit better. As `%*ENV` is Strings having a Boolean False is a bit of a pain.

Comment: Nice. I thought along the same lines. I've too many things on my plate (eg an SNS messaging module for Cro?) but a couple things struck me when I pondered it, and again as I just read your answer. First, classes presumably would or least could be arranged such that *all* the attributes in a class with such attributes would repeat the trait, as in your example. Second, `:required` is, roughly, `is required`. Thus the thought: could one write a *class* trait that iterates over the class's attributes at class composition time to do its thing and achieve the same effect with much less syntax?

Comment: I was having issues getting it to play nicely with is required. And the class trait could be a thing too. Timtowtdi :)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I wrote "roughly" -- and also why I gave up given my current backlog. Also, perhaps individual attribute traits is actually better. Timtowtdi indeed. :)