# How to add a class attribute dynamically?

Tags: metaprogramming, raku

How can I add an attribute to a class dynamically?  I tried this but it's complaining about a missing method and I'm not sure why since I'm not trying to add a method.

```
use v6.d;

class Foo does Metamodel::AttributeContainer {
    submethod BUILD(:$attr) {
        my $a = Attribute.new(:name($attr), :type(Str), :package(Foo));
        self.add_attribute(self, $a);
    }
}

my Foo $foo = Foo.new(:attr('bar'));
$foo.bar = 'baz';  # No such method 'bar' for invocant of type 'Foo'
say $foo.bar;
```

Comment: See also [How to add an attribute to an object using the meta-object protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51920051/2173773)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no way to add an attribute to a class once it has been composed - that is, after its closing curly `}` has been parsed. In general, declarative things done using the metamodel need to be done at compile time.

About the code that you have written in the question:

- Conceptually, attributes exist per class, not per object, so there's no way to make something like this work.
- Even putting that aside, doing the `Metamodel::AttributeContainer` role won't help anything here; it's to be composed into a meta-class, which holds the metadata about attributes, rather than the class that has the attributes being declared.
- The error about the method `bar` not being found is because an attribute accessor - even a generated one - is just an ordinary method.

It's hard to know what to suggest instead without knowing the problem you were trying to solve in the first place. Whatever it is, it can't be solved by trying to add attributes per-object. Perhaps consider either:

- Using mixins, which are a means to changing an individual object
- Having a class that contains a hash to store its data, and then using the `FALLBACK` method to resolve method calls into hash accesses for the valid keys

Comment: As you suggest, FALLBACK is exactly what I'm already doing to gain read access to a thing.  I have a hash and I grab the values from it based on the key.  I'm looking for a write version of FALLBACK that would allow me to update the value in my hash based on a key.

Comment: Add `is raw` to the `FALLBACK` method and it'll return the l-value, so it can then be assigned to.

Comment: I got it working.  Thank you.  I got hung up for a while on a guard clause.. just plain old `%!attrs{$name};` worked where `return %!attrs{$name} if %!attrs{$name};` failed with a readonly error.  I re-arranged things to use a proper if/else and it worked.

Comment: Since the submethod approach only adds *one* custom attribute, you could simply store `$!custom_attribute` and `$!custom_attribute_name`.

Comment: @gdonald You can also use `return-rw`